# Validate dropdown list with values from databse in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I am trying to validate a dropdown list. The items of the list is taking from database and is shown below.

```
       <select class="form-control" name="clstechid">
          <option value="0">Select</option>
          @foreach($persons as $person)
            @if($person->ttype == 1)
              <option value="{{$person->id}}">{{$person->tname}}</option>
            @endif
          @endforeach
        </select>
```

I want to validate this dropdown menu. The selected item should not be 'Select' option. How will I validate?? Can anyone help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set the value attribute to a null value:

```
<option value="">Select</option>
```

Answer (score 2):

Theres a really nice way to do this in Laravel using the lists function on a Collection.

Controller

```
$select = ['' => 'Please Select'] + $persons->where('ttype', 1)->lists('tname', 'id');

return view('my.view', compact('select'));
```

View

```
 {!! Form::select('clstechid', $select) !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change Val from 0 to

`<option value="">-- Select --</option>`